# JSON Bulk load with Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache, hbase, bulkinsert, apache-phoenix

I have a problem with loading data from json files. How can i export data from json files into the table in Hbase?

Here is json-structure:

```
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "53ba5e86eb07565b53374901"} , "_api_method" : "database.getSchools" , "id" : "0" , "date_insert" : "2014-07-07 11:47:02" , "unixdate" : 1404722822 , "city_id" : "1506490" , "response" : [ 1 , { "id" : 354053 , "title" : "шк. Аджамская"}]};
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

For your json format, you could not use importtsv. I suggest you write a Mapreduce to parse you json data and put data to HBase.